# uploading file with multer

Tags: javascript, express, multer, uploading

I am a js-newbie and I am currently trying to use multer to upload some files.
Here is my code:

```
let express = require('express');
let im = require('imagemagick');
let gm = require("gm").subClass({
    imageMagick: true
});
let multer  = require('multer');

let app = express();

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage}).single('avatar');

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: 'error during uploading'
            });
        } else if (err) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                message: 'error during uploading'
            });
        }

        res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Image uploaded'
        });
    })
})

app.listen(3000);
```

When I send a post-req with a file (form-data), then I get a success message, however **the folder with the file is not created**:

[post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkH0W.png)

**EDIT:**

I managed to upload the file... I had to change the path of the uploads directory in the code like this:

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
});
```

However the *uploads* directory hast to be created manually, it is not being created automatically if it is missing...how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this issue out:
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/287

It says you should create a directory in 'destination' or as pre-requirements.